# XCB window geometry/surface dimensions appear to be stale despite reconfigure

Tags: c, vulkan, xcb

I was working with Vulkan on an XCB-provided window surface under my own windowing abstraction but encountered a rather strange behaviour when recreating the swapchain on recieving a window reconfigure event (`XCB_CONFIGURE_NOTIFY`).

The values returned by `xcb_get_geometry` appear to stay as the initial values for the window. i.e. if I created a window of extent 640x480 at (0,0), drag it elsewhere on the screen and resize it - the values returned by `xcb_get_geometry` will still be 640x480 at (0,0). I tried explicitly flushing and reconfiguring the window to some other value to see whether it was just a case of the events being delivered erroneously - but even though I could see the window visually resizing, `xcb_get_geometry` still remained the same.

The reason this was highlighted was that Validation Layers (Actual message attached below) notified me the extent I had specified to `vkCreateSwapchain` was outside the range of acceptable values according to `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR` - also 640x480 despite the window visually being resized and a resize event having been delivered. This too persisted even if I explicitly reconfigured the window before recreating the swapchain.

I feel like I may be missing some sort of surface-resize proc I should be calling, or maybe I have to wait a frame before resizing but I am not sure.

There is a lot of code but I can point out some relevant parts - it's all under [this repo](https://github.com/Th3T3chn0G1t/Genstone/).

> `genstone/genfx/genuwin.c:361` Event polling code - configuration requests are buffered into separate position and window events delivered on the two subsequent calls to the one where the event is actually processed.

> `genstone/genfx/gengfx.c:902` Swapchain recreation code - shouldn't be problematic as far as I can see and the issue does appear to be on the side of my XCB abstraction but probably better to share as much info as possible.

> `sandbox/sample/main.c:240` Handling of wrapped Genuwin event and dispatching call to `gen_internal_vk_create_swapchain`.

The validation error which signalled this (Without Validation Layers submitting `VkQueue` results in failure):

```
Fatal: Validation Error: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR-imageExtent-01274 ] Object 0: handle = 0x62d000168450, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x7cd0911d | vkCreateSwapchainKHR() called with imageExtent = (792,605), which is outside the bounds returned by vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR(): currentExtent = (640,480), minImageExtent = (640,480), maxImageExtent = (640,480). The Vulkan spec states: imageExtent must be between minImageExtent and maxImageExtent, inclusive, where minImageExtent and maxImageExtent are members of the VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR structure returned by vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR for the surface (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR-imageExtent-01274)
Trace: frame #0: 0x0x7f4c9a0afa00 gen_internal_vk_debug_callback() genstone/genfx/gengfx.c
Trace: frame #1: 0x0x7f4c9a0b33e0 gen_internal_vk_create_swapchain() genstone/genfx/gengfx.c
Trace: frame #2: 0x0x7f4c9a0baaa0 gen_gfx_targetable_geometry_update() genstone/genfx/gengfx.c
Trace: frame #3: 0x0x563b13ebcbc0 main() sandbox/sample/main.c
```

The backtrace is missing any code not tooled by me but you get the idea.

I am using XCB 1.15-1 (according to `pacman`), and I have submoduled all the Vulkan "stuff" I use (Validation Layers, headers, loader) so they're all up to date with their trunks (at the time I'm posting).

Comment: That's a lot of code to look at, so here is another idea to hopefully help you debug this yourself: You have your window id. Can you `printf` or log it or something like that? Once you know the ID of your window, you can run `xwininfo -id 0x1234` in a terminal. This prints (among other things) the size and position of your window.

Comment: @UliSchlachter thanks! `xwininfo` also seems to return a stale value? The window is pretty clearly not 640x480 here but https://imgur.com/a/szQm5Ra

Comment: Sorry, that link only gives me a gray browser window. Dunno what's up with imgur. Anyway, if `xwininfo` reports the same size, then that is not stale, but "the truth". So... are there other windows involved? `xwininfo -root -tree` gives you a full list of all windows with their sizes and positions. Is there some other window "nearby" that has the expected size, or something? Are you somehow making your window non-resizable, or so (yeah, this question is not helpful and I have no clue how to check whether `ResizeRedirect` was requested...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. You are indeed making your window non-resizable by selecting `XCB_EVENT_MASK_RESIZE_REDIRECT` on the window here: https://github.com/Th3T3chn0G1t/Genstone/blob/c8759b6687bb83045b8fe58b03c2575276940ca7/genstone/genfx/genuwin.c#L741-L743

Thanks to this, you only get ResizeRequest events instead of actually being resized, see: https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html#events:ResizeRequest

That whole event mask looks like "this seriously needs some line breaks for readability", but also "I am just selecting every event there is". I suggest to just ask for the events that you are really interested in. Just selecting an event already has side-effects and ResizeRedirect is not the only such event mask.

I found https://github.com/Th3T3chn0G1t/Genstone/blob/c8759b6687bb83045b8fe58b03c2575276940ca7/genstone/genfx/genuwin.c#L394-L722 and it looks like you are only interested in few of the events. You can find which event mask you need for which event on https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html.

Comment: Awesome! I was definitely getting actual reconfigure events but IG the same applies. Thank you ^-^